# Проблема с запуском .sh скрипта

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, sh

Пытался сделать удобную настройку фаервола на множестве машин и столкнулся с ошибкой запуска.

Несколько часов просидел за Яндексом, протестировал скрипт в ShellCheck - никаких ошибок не нашёл, поэтому надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Система: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Команды использую с суперпользователя.

Сам скрипт:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    ...

    "firewall")
        case "$2" in
            "start")
                # Получаем IP текущей машины.
                IP=$(grep "$(hostname)" /etc/hosts | awk '{print $1}')
            
                # Удаляем все имеющиеся правила и цепочки.
                iptables -F
                iptables -X
                echo "Удалены имеющиеся правила и цепочки..."
            
                # Устанавливаем всем пакетам стандартное значение "DROP".
                iptables -P INPUT DROP
                iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
                iptables -P FORWARD DROP
                echo "Заблокированы все входящие и исходящие пакеты..."
            
                # Разрешаем обмен данными в локальной сети.
                iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
                iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
                echo "Разрешён обмен пакетами в локальной сети..."
            
                # Разрешаем доступ к машине с определённых IP адресов.
                for var in "$@"; do
                    if [ "$var" != "firewall" ] && [ "$var" != "start" ]; then
                        iptables -A INPUT -s "$var" -d "$IP" -j ACCEPT
                        iptables -A OUTPUT -s "$IP" -d "$var" -j ACCEPT
                        echo "Предоставлен полный доступ для IP $var..."
                    fi
                done
                
                unset IP
                ;;
                
            ...
                
            *)
                echo " > Действие фаервола '$2' не обнаружено."
                ;;
        esac
        ;;

    *)
        echo " > Действие '$1' не обнаружено."
        ;;
esac
```

Ошибка:

```
: not found: 2:
```

Comment: А переносы строк в LF у вас?

Comment: @void, было в "CR LF", благодарю. Отправьте как ответ, помечу решением, как станет доступно.

Comment: _Useless use of more_... `grep` Умеет файлы открывать, сюрприз!

Comment: @0andriy, не особо разбираюсь в командах linux'a, поэтому про нюансы работы некоторых из них не в курсе) Благодарю, доработал.

Comment: Раз пошла такая пьянка, то весь ворох сравнений лучше в `case "$1" ... esac` поместить. Это смотрится натуральнее в Shell. Ну и понятно, что обрабатывается быстрее, так как нет множественного форка `test` (и да, я знаю, что в некоторых shell'ах `test` -- это встроенная команда).

Comment: @0andriy, снова благодарствую, оказывается здесь и case есть, вообще замечательно)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас, скорее всего, переносы строк в коде обозначены как CRLF. Вам необходимо реализовать переносы строк в LF.